# How to communicate across multiple Qt Widgets that all share a model

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have a collection widgets in a mainwindow that all work with a single bit of data on a model, I've attached a drawing of the structure below. Currently only the tree widget has access to the model and also has a treeview. Communication with the other widgets is done through signals and slots. When a new selection is made in the tree, every other widget on the screen changes to represent the new selected tree node. This works, however sending signals through one widget to all others is extremely cumbersome.

I'd like to pass the model that the tree uses to all the other widgets and make it work off of the signals that the model sends upon any changes to it. So instead of having all the classes sending signals  to each other communication can be done through the model itself.

I've created and passed a model to the tree and the other widgets in the main window class's constructor but I'm not sure how I should proceed from this point as I am relatively unfamiliar with MVC. The tree class is the only class with a view at this point, do I need to add views to the other classes as well to be able to get access to signals that are emitted when a certain field is selected or would the model be enough?.

I'd appreciate any input, thanks.

[image: Widget Structure]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, notify model if something changed and make it emit signal, subscribe to that signal in relevant widgets. In other words decouple widgets from each other removing widget-widget subscriptions, subscribe only to model.

Answer (score 1):

Selection is not a property of the model, but of the view. Multiple views can be attached to a single model, each displaying a different "item". Thus, there is no out of the box method to signal a change in selection from the model itself.

There is a dedicated [`QItemSelectionModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html) class, that deals with exactely what you need: keep track of selection on a single model across multiple views.

You would wrap your data model in a selection model and base your communication upon it, e.g.:

```
MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow() {
   myModel = new MyModel;
   treeView = new MyTreeView(myModel);
   QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = new QItemSelectionModel(myModel);
   treeView->setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
   detailWidget = new MyDetailWidget(this, selectionModel);
}

////////////

MyDetailWidget::MyDetailWidget(QWidget *parent, QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel) {
   // React to changed selection
   connect(selectionModel, &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged, this, 
     [=](auto current, auto /*previous*/) { 
       updateView(current);
     }
   );

   // React to change in selected item
   connect(selectionModel->model(), &QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged, this,
     [=](auto topLeft, auto bottomRight, auto /*roles*/) {
       QItemSelection sel(topLeft, bottomRight);
       if (sel.contains(selectionModel->currentIndex()) {
          updateView(selectionModel->currentIndex());
       }
     }
   );
}

void MyDetailWidget::updateView(const QModelIndex &idx) {
   // Assume some label on this widget
   m_name->setText(idx.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
}
```